# React и bootstrap стили

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs

Я пишу react компоненты с использованием bootstrap (обычный bootstrap не reactstrap или что-то ещё). В интерфейсе есть динамические элементы типа модальных окон, чего-то анимированного.

Могу ли я в зависимости от состояния добавлять css класс к элементу чтобы отрабатывала анимация

```
<div className="modal {this.state.isVisible ? 'show' : ''}">
```

И вообще правильно ли использовать обычный bootstrap в react приложении?

Comment: Для чего вам bootstrap?

Comment: Стили из bootstrap-а использую, сетку (row, col-lg-*), модалки, да вообще много чего

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно. Для удобства я еще посоветовал использовать библиотеку "classnames".

```js
import cn from 'classnames'

...

render() {
  const { isVisible } = this.state;

  return (
    ...
      <div className={cn('modal', isVisible && 'show')}>
    ...
  )
}
```

удобство этой библиотеки в том, что если условие вернёт false то в className 'false' не добавиться